# Renaming files in a folder in Windows using Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

In a directory, I have some `.jpg` files.

- The file names are integers starting from `1.jpg` to `150.jpg`.
- I would like to subtract `1` from each file name.
- So the file names would be `0.jpg` to `149.jpg`.

I know how to replace some characters in the file name using `PowerShell`.

How can I achieve this with `Powershell`?

Following are the `Powershell` scripts which I tried.

**Powershell Script**

```
gci *.jpg | rename-item -newname {[integer]($_.name -replace ".JPG", "")-1}
```

And:

```
gci *.JPG | rename-item -newname { (([convert]::ToInt32($_.name, 10)) - 1) + ".JPG"}
```

Comment: You don't need to. Just start renaming from `0`. I will post an answer in a moment.

Comment: Answer written..

Comment: @Ullas or you could use Bulk Rename Utility

Comment: As an aside, for these kinds of things, I've always found Python to be easier to work with then a Powershell (or bash) script. Perhaps not quite as compact, but generally easier to work with and much easier to find resources for (by googling things like "python list files in folder" or "python rename file").

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### File names should be like 0.jpg to 149.jpg

Use the following PowerShell command:

```
dir *.jpg | Sort-Object { [regex]::Replace($_.Name, '\d+', { $args[0].Value.PadLeft(20) }) } | foreach-object -begin { $count=0 } -process { rename-item $_ -NewName "$count.jpg"; $count++ }
```

Notes:

- `$count=0` start counting from `0`.
- `$_` represents each item passed to the rename-item command via the pipe `|` from the `dir` command.
- `foreach-object` allows you to set a variable (`$count`) before looping through each file in the directory (matching `*.jpg`) and then perform an action (`rename-item`) for each matching item.
- To sort the `dir` output in a "natural" sort order, we use:

  ```
  Sort-Object { [regex]::Replace($_.Name, '\d+', { args[0].Value.PadLeft(20) }) }
  ```

Example:

```
PS F:\test> dir *.jpg

    Directory: F:\test

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---        01/04/2016     19:39         54 1.jpg
-a---        01/04/2016     19:39         54 10.jpg
-a---        01/04/2016     19:39         52 11.jpg
-a---        01/04/2016     19:39         54 2.jpg
-a---        01/04/2016     19:39         54 3.jpg
-a---        01/04/2016     19:35         52 4.jpg
-a---        01/04/2016     19:35         52 5.jpg
-a---        01/04/2016     19:39         51 6.jpg
-a---        01/04/2016     19:39         51 7.jpg
-a---        01/04/2016     19:39         54 8.jpg
-a---        01/04/2016     19:39         52 9.jpg


PS F:\test> dir *.jpg | Sort-Object { [regex]::Replace($_.Name, '\d+', { $args[0].Value.PadLeft(20) }) } | foreach-object -begin { $count=0 } -process { rename-item $_ -NewName "$count.jpg"; $count++}

PS F:\test> dir *.jpg

    Directory: F:\test


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---        01/04/2016     19:39         54 0.jpg
-a---        01/04/2016     19:39         54 1.jpg
-a---        01/04/2016     19:39         52 10.jpg
-a---        01/04/2016     19:39         54 2.jpg
-a---        01/04/2016     19:35         52 3.jpg
-a---        01/04/2016     19:35         52 4.jpg
-a---        01/04/2016     19:39         51 5.jpg
-a---        01/04/2016     19:39         51 6.jpg
-a---        01/04/2016     19:39         54 7.jpg
-a---        01/04/2016     19:39         52 8.jpg
-a---        01/04/2016     19:39         54 9.jpg

PS F:\test>
```

Source: [Batch File Rename with Windows PowerShell](http://tweaks.com/windows/49459/batch-file-rename-with-windows-powershell/). Script has been tweaked to match the requirements of the question.

Source: [How to sort by file name the same way Windows Explorer does?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5429048/3536342) answer by [Roman Kuzmin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/323582/roman-kuzmin) for natural sorting.

Comment: Sir excuse me, its not processing properly. Error : `rename-item : Cannot create a file when that file already exists.`

Comment: Sir, I think the problem happens because after renaming `1.JPG` then `10.JPG` instead of `2.JPG` and so on.

Comment: Yes it is..,, After renaming `1.JPG` to `0.JPG` it is renaming `10.JPG` to `2.JPG`..

Comment: Sir, I did 1 thing. Created 3 sub folders. 1. `1.JPG  to  9.JPG`, 2.`10.JPG  to 99.JPG` and 3.`100.JPG  to 150.JPG` and I changed `$count` accordingly and its working fine.

Comment: I've updated the answer to fix the sort issue.

Comment: You've achieved knighthood, sir David of Superuser

Comment: @Raystafarian LOL ;)